# How to organize list of models for stargazer?

Tags: r, stargazer, plm

I have a large dataset in which I want to partition into 13 pieces (by `Subsetor`). In each one of them, I would run 4 different `plm`, varying only the dependent variable.

I would also like to use cluster robust standard errors using `coeftest` and `vcovHC`. Here is some sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lmtest)
library(sandwich)
library(broom)

df <- structure(list(Subsetor = c("Footwear", "Footwear", "Machinery", 
"Machinery"), mmc = c(31028, 22902, 33013, 35017), MassaSalarial_SM_Real = c(0, 
0, 0, 2758.78039259859), Ano = c(1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, 1992), Vinculos = c(0, 0, 0, 536), Estab = c(0, 
0, 1, 8), salario_real_capita_SM = c(NaN, NaN, NaN, 5.14697834440035
), tarifa_peso_VAB_1990 = c(0.193475, 0.5756, 0.258589287604088, 
0.258589287604088)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(Subsetor = c("Footwear", 
"Machinery"), .rows = list(1:2, 3:4)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

First I ran regressions considering each dependent variable for each type in `Subsetor`:

```
Model_Vinculos <- df %>%
  mutate(salario_real_capita_SM = salario_real_capita_SM %>% 
           replace(., is.na(.), 0)) %>%
  group_by(Subsetor) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, 
                     ~plm(log(Vinculos + 1) ~ log(tarifa_peso_VAB_1990),
                          data = . ,
                          model = 'within',
                          effects = 'twoways',
                          index = c('mmc', 'Ano'))),
         erros.padrao = map(model, ~coeftest(., vcovHC(., type = 'HC0', 
                                                       cluster = 'group'))),
         inf = map(model, broom::tidy)) %>%
  select(Subsetor, inf, erros.padrao, model)
```

I've repeated this process creating 3 other objects: `Model_Estab`, `Model_MassaSalarial` and `Model_Salario`.

Afterwards I've binded them and also extracted my desired information, namely the coefficients and the robust standard errors:

```
Models_Subsetor <- list(
  Estabelecimentos = Model_Estab,
  Massa_Salarial = Model_MassaSalarial,
  Remuneracao = Model_Salario,
  Vinculos = Model_Vinculos
) %>%
  bind_rows(.id  = 'id') %>%
  select(Subsetor, inf, erros.padrao, id) %>%
  unnest(cols = c(inf)) %>%
  select(Subsetor, estimate, erros.padrao, id) %>%
  mutate(erros.padrao = map(erros.padrao, broom::tidy)) %>%
  mutate(se = erros.padrao %>% map_dbl(~ .x[['std.error']])) %>%
  select(id, Subsetor, estimate, se) %>%
  gather(estimate:se, key = 'key', value = 'value') %>%
  spread(id, value)
```

Now I would like to use these results with `stargazer`. By simply priting the `Models_Subsetor`
wouldn't be ideal, since the table wouldn't exactly be formatted as a regression table.

My question therefore is what is the easiest way to get a stargazer table that resembles this one, but that is like a regression table (with asterisks according to p-values, removing the parts where 'se' is written, putting standard erros inside parenthesis, allowing me to add rows with some other custom observations and so on).

Comment: Can you give a more minimal example? Its not reproducable for me, since you don't define `Ano` in df. What restriction to you face when saving plm models and putting them directly into stargazer?

Comment: @MarcoDoe sorry, just edited my data - I forgot a column. My issue is that I actually have to run 13 x 4 = 52 regressions. (i.e. four dependent variables for 13 subsets of the database). In that spirit, I would like stargazer to give me something that resembles ```Models_Subsetor```. However, if I just list all of my models, stargazer would give me a 52 x 1 regression table, which is far from ideal

Comment: Still not working for me. A minimal example would have been more helpful. Further I don't see how exactly your ideal output would look like. You could show 4 different models over 13 sectors in 4 tables. In plain stargazer (it accepts lists). You want to put everything on a DINA4 page?

Comment: To me it would be better to show everything in a single table. There would be 13 rows (sectors) and 4 columns (models). Each value would represent the same coefficient, since all models have the same independent variable